# unable to populate listview in fragment layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I"m new to android development and currently going through udacity course on developing android apps. I've looked for all the possible answers but none of them worked. My code looks perfectly fine to me and I'm not getting any error in the log as well. but unfortunately my output is blank. nothing is showing up.

this is my java code:
1. MainActivity.java.

```
package com.example.vineet_kr.sunshine;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

2.mainActivityFragment.java

```
package com.example.vineet_kr.sunshine;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        String[] data = {
                                     "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                                     "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                                     "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                                     "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                                     "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                                     "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                                     "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
                            };
        List<String> WeekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
        ArrayAdapter<String> forecast = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textView,WeekForecast );
        View  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);
        list.setAdapter(forecast);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

here are the Xml files.
1.list_Item_forecast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textView"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>
```

2.fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vineet_kr.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView_forecast"
         />

</FrameLayout>
```

3.content_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.vineet_kr.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

4. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
   ```

Comment: please paste activity_main.xml

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir done